# Jest + Material-UI : Correctly mocking useMediaQuery

Tags: jestjs, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI's `useMediaQuery()` function in one of my components to determine the `size` prop to use for a `<Button>` within the component.

I'm trying to test that it's working as expected in a jest test, however my current implementation isn't working:

```js
describe("Unit: <Navbar> On xs screens", () => {

  // Incorrectly returns `matches` as `false` ****************************
  window.matchMedia = jest.fn().mockImplementation(
    query => {
      return {
        matches: true,
        media: query,
        onchange: null,
        addListener: jest.fn(),
        removeListener: jest.fn()
      };
    }
  );

  it("renders as snapshot", async () => {
    const width = theme.breakpoints.values.sm - 1;
    const height = Math.round((width * 9) / 16);
    Object.defineProperty(window, "innerWidth", {
      writable: true,
      configurable: true,
      value: width
    });
    const { asFragment } = render(
      <Container backgroundColor={"#ffffff"}>
        <Navbar />
      </Container>
    );
    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
    const screenshot = await generateImage({
      viewport: { width, height }
    });
    expect(screenshot).toMatchImageSnapshot();
  });
});

describe("Unit: <Navbar> On md and up screens", () => {

  // Correctly returns `matches` as `false` ****************************
  window.matchMedia = jest.fn().mockImplementation(
    query => {
      return {
        matches: false,
        media: query,
        onchange: null,
        addListener: jest.fn(),
        removeListener: jest.fn()
      };
    }
  );

  it("renders as snapshot", async () => {
    const width = theme.breakpoints.values.md;
    const height = Math.round((width * 9) / 16);
    Object.defineProperty(window, "innerWidth", {
      writable: true,
      configurable: true,
      value: width
    });
    const { asFragment } = render(
      <Container backgroundColor={"#ffffff"}>
        <Navbar />
      </Container>
    );
    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
    const screenshot = await generateImage({
      viewport: { width, height }
    });
    expect(screenshot).toMatchImageSnapshot();
  });
});
```

And the component I'm testing (removed irrelevant parts):

```js
const Navbar = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const matchXs = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("xs"));
  return (
    <Button size={matchXs ? "medium" : "large"}>
      Login
    </Button>
  );
};
export default Navbar;
```

It's returning `matches` as `false` for the first test, even though I've set it to return as true. I know this because it's generating a screenshot and I can see that the button size is set to `large` for the first test when it should be set to `medium`.

It works as expected in production.

How do I correctly get mock `useMediaQuery()` in a jest test?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The recommended way is using [`css-mediaquery`](https://github.com/ericf/css-mediaquery) which is now mentioned in [the MUI docs](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/#testing):

```js
import mediaQuery from 'css-mediaquery';

function createMatchMedia(width) {
  return query => ({
    matches: mediaQuery.match(query, { width }),
    addListener: () => {},
    removeListener: () => {},
  });
}

describe('MyTests', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    window.matchMedia = createMatchMedia(window.innerWidth);
  });
});
```

Comment: new link: https://mui.com/components/use-media-query/#testing

Answer (score 4):

A simple approach that worked for me:

`component.tsx`

```js
import { Fade, Grid, useMediaQuery } from '@material-ui/core';

...
const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(max-width:600px)');
```

`component.spec.tsx`

```js
import { useMediaQuery } from '@material-ui/core';

// not testing for mobile as default
jest.mock('@material-ui/core', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@material-ui/core'),
  useMediaQuery: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(false),
}));

describe('...', () => {
it(...)

// test case for mobile
it('should render something for mobile', () => {
  ((useMediaQuery as unknown) as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(true);
  ....
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out...

`useMediaQuery()` needs to re-render the component to work, as the first render will return whatever you define in `options.defaultMatches` (`false` by default).

Also, the mock needs to be scoped to each test (`it`), not in the `describe`.

As I'm using react-testing-library, all I have to do is re-render the component again and change the scope of the mock and it works.

Here's the working example:

```js
const initTest = width => {
  Object.defineProperty(window, "innerWidth", {
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    value: width
  });
  window.matchMedia = jest.fn().mockImplementation(
    query => {
      return {
        matches: width >= theme.breakpoints.values.sm ? true : false,
        media: query,
        onchange: null,
        addListener: jest.fn(),
        removeListener: jest.fn()
      };
    }
  );
  const height = Math.round((width * 9) / 16);
  return { width, height };
};

describe("Unit: <Navbar> On xs screens", () => {
  it("renders as snapshot", async () => {
    const { width, height } = initTest(theme.breakpoints.values.sm - 1);
    const { asFragment, rerender} = render(
      <Container backgroundColor={"#ffffff"}>
        <Navbar />
      </Container>
    );
    rerender(
      <Container backgroundColor={"#ffffff"}>
        <Navbar />
      </Container>
    );
    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
    const screenshot = await generateImage({
      viewport: { width, height }
    });
    expect(screenshot).toMatchImageSnapshot();
  });
});

describe("Unit: <Navbar> On md and up screens", () => {
  it("renders as snapshot", async () => {
    const { width, height } = initTest(theme.breakpoints.values.md);
    const { asFragment } = render(
      <Container backgroundColor={"#ffffff"}>
        <Navbar />
      </Container>
    );
    rerender(
      <Container backgroundColor={"#ffffff"}>
        <Navbar />
      </Container>
    );
    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
    const screenshot = await generateImage({
      viewport: { width, height }
    });
    expect(screenshot).toMatchImageSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [@iman-mahmoudinasab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997229/iman-mahmoudinasab)'s accepted answer, here is a TypeScript implementation. Essentially, we would want to create valid `MediaQueryList`-object:

```js
// yarn add -D css-mediaquery @types/css-mediaquery
import mediaQuery from 'css-mediaquery';

describe('Foo Bar', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    function createMatchMedia(width: number) {
      return (query: string): MediaQueryList => ({
        matches: mediaQuery.match(query, { width }) as boolean,
        media: '',
        addListener: () => {},
        removeListener: () => {},
        onchange: () => {},
        addEventListener: () => {},
        removeEventListener: () => {},
        dispatchEvent: () => true,
      });
    }
    // mock matchMedia for useMediaQuery to work properly
    window.matchMedia = createMatchMedia(window.innerWidth);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can do something like this:

```js
const applyMock = (mobile) => {
  window.matchMedia = jest.fn().mockImplementation((query) => {
    return {
      matches: mobile,
      media: query,
      addListener: jest.fn(),
      removeListener: jest.fn(),
    };
  });
};
```

and use it like this:

```js
const mockMediaQueryForMobile = () => applyMock(true);
const mockMediaQueryForDesktop = () => applyMock(false);
```